# D3 fade function Circle Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hey Guys i need some help to find a way to integrate the switch of images into the fade function. For some reason the chords dont fade after the mouse hovers over the graph.

And to Look at the idea of loading (but not displaying) a series of images during initial page load, and then using the fade function simply to switch a pre-defined image area to show a different image.

[This is my JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/leduwopimo/edit?html,output)

Comment: think you should be doing     `.on("mouseout", function(e){

      fade(1)(e);
      // hide image
      overlayPic.classList.add('hidden');
    });` for the fade to go away on mouse out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass data bonded to the arc and it's index as parameter to the function which is returned by the fade function as shown below.

```
d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius))
    .on('mouseover', function(d,i) {
      fade(0.1)(d,i); //Changed line of code
      overlayPic.classList.remove('hidden');
      overlayPic.src = 'https://farm1.staticflickr.com/697/23125850325_b69a8530dd_n.jpg';
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d,i){
      fade(1)(d,i);  //Changed line of code
      overlayPic.classList.add('hidden');
    });
```

Fade function expects that two params.

```
function fade(opacity) {
  return function(g, i) { //Note that this code uses index i
    svg.selectAll(".chord path")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i; })
        .transition()
        .style("opacity", opacity);
  };
}
```